# Find rotation so that line doesn't intersect with circle

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, euclidean-geometry, collision-detection

Hello math stackexchange community,

We have **x** as starting point, **v** as unit normalized direction, **c** as center of a circle and **r** as the radius of the circle.

To find if the line described as **x** + $\alpha$  **v** intersects the circle we can take the discriminant of the quadratic equation $||x + \alpha v - c||^2 < r^2$ and conclude if and how many collisions are there.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyM1p.png)

But how can we find the angle **beta** so that rotating **v** by **beta** would lead to line **x** + $\alpha$  rotate(**v**, **beta**) which doesn't intersect the circle?

Greetings, James!

Comment: Find the tangents from $\mathbf{x}$ to your circle. These two tangents will make angles $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$ with $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}$, the vector connecting your point with the circle's center. In order for your line to not intersect the circle, you want the angle between your direction vector and $\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{c}$ to not be in the interval $(-\alpha,\alpha)$. Can you take it from here? (This problem would be much more nicely approached using Euclidean geometry but you can adapt the argument easily to vectors)

Answer (score 1):

@Tanny Sieben Thank you! The idea to use the tangent is genius!

The angle between the tangent and the line pointing towards the center of the circle - $x + \alpha q$ - is $gamma = arcsin(r/d)$ where **d** is the distance from **x** to **c** and $q = \frac{c-x}{||c-x||^2}$ unit normalized direction vector.

The angle between $x + \alpha q$ and $x + \alpha v$ is $tau = arccos(q * v)$.

And $beta = gamma - tau$